# Facebook Login wont work on mod_rewrited urls

Tags: php, facebook, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Facebook sign in worked perfectly until i created .htaccess and rewrote URL-s 
Now when i pressing on sign in button its changing link and adding ?code= and after this if i'm pressing from homepage its signing me in but if it on rewrote page its doing nothing. I have tried to change rewrite rules.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^movie/([^/]*)$ /?movie=$1
RewriteRule ^movie/([^/]*)/credits$ /?movie=$1&dir=movie_credits
RewriteRule ^movie/([^/]*)/images$ /?movie=$1&dir=movie_images
RewriteRule ^tv/([^/]*)$ /?tv=$1
RewriteRule ^tv/([^/]*)/credits$ /?tv=$1&dir=tv_credits
RewriteRule ^tv/([^/]*)/images$ /?tv=$1&dir=tv_images
RewriteRule ^name/([^/]*)$ /?person=$1
RewriteRule ^name/([^/]*)/credits$ /?person=$1&dir=person_credits
RewriteRule ^name/([^/]*)/images$ /?person=$1&dir=person_images
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]*)$ /?user=$1
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]*)/movies/favlist$ /?user=$1&dir=movies_favlist
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]*)/movies/watchlist$ /?user=$1&dir=movies_watchlist
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]*)/people/favlist$ /?user=$1&dir=people_favlist
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]*)/tv/favlist$ /?user=$1&dir=tv_favlist
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]*)/tv/watchlist$ /?user=$1&dir=tv_watchlist
RewriteRule ^genre/([^/]*)$ /?discover&genres=$1
RewriteRule ^genre/tv/([^/]*)$ /?discover=tv&genres=$1
RewriteRule ^tv/([^/]*)/season/([^/]*)$ /?tv=$1&dir=seasons&season=$2


RewriteRule ^discover/movies$ /?discover
RewriteRule ^discover/tv$ /?discover=tv
RewriteRule ^discover/people$ /?people
RewriteRule ^discover/people/page([^/]*)$ /?people&page=$1
RewriteRule ^discover/users$ /?users
RewriteRule ^register$ /?user=register
```

Comment: Please share more detail. Also, avoid run-on sentences please. being pretty is nice

Comment: I rewrite urls and now when i am trying to sign in with Facebook its redirecting to Facebook and then to my website back but nothing happens if urls like this mywebsite/post/11 but if its like mywebsite/?post=1 its working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

there's more to your htaccess file that needs to be looked at if you don't want an answer that's fine, but you need to show more

Comment: I have changed question and there is whole my .htaccess